# Room Password Question - Limited Memory

Tags: combinatorics

To get into a room, you need to enter a code, which has maximum length 4 and consists of the letters A-E (letters may be repeated). The code panel knows the length of the code and will preserve the last number of buttons pressed equal to the length of the code. For example, if the panel knows the code is 2 letters long and I entered ABECD, the panel would only remember CD. What is the shortest sequences of letters you can use to guarantee you have included the correct code?

Answer (score 0):

There are many such sequence, but we can at least detemine the length of these.
Since there are $5^4$ codes, the length must be at least $5^4+3$ (a new code is tried with avery key press except the first three).

Here's how one can generate one such sequence: Start with $AAAA$ and from then on, if the last three letters where $\alpha\beta\gamma$ pick the alphabetically first ketter $\delta$ for which the combinaton $\alpha\beta\gamma\delta$ has not been tested before. Stop when there is no such $\delta$.

Assume that not all codes are covered by this sequence and pick one such  omitted code $xyzw$ of minimal weight (where the weight of $A$ is $\operatorname{wt}(A)=0$, that of $B$ is $\operatorname{wt}(B)=1$ etc.) and among those of minimal weight the lexicographically first.
Then the sequence $xyz$ occurs $\operatorname{wt}(w)$ times, once for each code $xyzw'$ with $\operatorname{wt}(w')<\operatorname{wt}(w)$. Continuing along this line one ultimately arrives at a contradiction.

Comment: I'm afraid your construction doesn't work. If I'm not making a mistake, it produces $AAAABAAACAAADAAAEAAA$, which certainly isn't the desired sequence.

Comment: There are actually $6^4-1$ passwords: $4$ is the **maximum** length, not the length.